# Remove PHP script from Laravel ecosystem

Tags: php, laravel

I need to put in my domain directories a simple php script that have to run isolated from the rest of my laravel application.

For example if my Laravel app run on `www.example.com`.
If I call `www.example.com/do_something_here/` 
and this `do_something_here` is a subfolder of my project that do not respond by the rules of Laravel routes.

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want that folder response by the rules of Laravel routes?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Comment: I've not idea how do what I asked, and nothing online help me about it. So.. as last chance I try to call an help to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you situation if your folder in public directory then (folder name should be: do_something_here)

change your .htaccess file for permission to access the folder. 
so that user can direct view your folder

Example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it. Whatever request comes to your site, it will hit your `index.php`. Present inside the `public/` directory and then the routing, classloading processes happens.

You might want to add some rules there in the `index.php`(you can write it just after the `<?php` line.) before the application bootstrapping happens, by checking the request URL, (`$_REQUEST`) and execute specific scripts and return.

One other way is to add rules in the `.htaccess` file if it's enabled. a quick google will find you way

Answer (score 0):

You can just add your folder `do_something_here/` in Laravel's `public/` folder. Any script placed inside `do_something_here/` can be called.

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle this is to use routes, catch all for any other page.

**Routes**

```
Route::get('functionName/{slugFolderName}/{slugFileName}', [
'uses' => 'PageController@getPage'
```

])->where('slug', '([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)');

```
This will match slugs like
test-page/sub-page
another-page/sub-page
```

**Controller**

```
public function getPage($slugFolderName,$slugFileName){
    return view($slugFolderName.$slugFileName);
}
```

**Hope this structure will help you**